# funsafe-math-optimizations, same formula on two different lines, different result

Tags: c++, math, gcc, optimization

I have the following code in a loop:

```
while(true)
{
    float i1, i2;

    if(y==0)
    {
        i1 = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        //if y==108, this gives 74.821136 (note the two last digits)
        i1 = ((values[y]+values[y+1])-values[1])*0.5f;
    }

    if(y+2==values.size())
    {
        i2 = values[y+1];
    }
    else
    {
        //if y==107, this gives 74.821129 (note the two last digits)
        i2 = ((values[y+1]+values[y+2])-values[1])*0.5f;
    }

    if(i1<=t && t<i2) {
        break;
    }
    else if(t<i1) {
        y--;
    }
    else {
        y++;
    }
}
```

This loop gets evaluated for y=107, t=74.821133

- i1 : 74.773773, i2 : **74.821129**

And for y=108:

- i1 : **74.821136**, i2 : 74.868484

As you can see, i2 when y=107 is slightly different from i1 when y=108, while the lines for calculating these two values are identical.

I understand that funsafe-math-optimizations reorganizes math formulas using algebra rules which may lead to numerical errors due finite precision. But here, two equivalent formulas seem optimized differently. Which in this example, lead to an infinite loop (as this function looks, for a given float t, the y value for which i1 <= t < i2 )

Is this a faulty gcc 4.8.0 behavior?

If I create a function:

```
float getDifValue(y) const { (values[y]+values[y+1])-values[1])*0.5f; }
```

And then use it in the loop:

```
    if(y==0)
    {
        i1 = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        i1 = getDifValue(y);
    }

    if(y+2==values.size())
    {
        i2 = values[y+1];
    }
    else
    {
        i2 = getDifValue(y+1);
    }
```

Am I ensured that i2 for y=107 and i1 for y=108 will produce the same result? Or can the compiler inline getDifValue and optimize it differently on both places?

Thanks

Comment: What are the values in you `values[]` array on index `107`-`110`, and `1`? And what kind of loop?

Comment: If you need *anything* being equal to *anything else*, unsafe is not for you. `x==x` *might* work, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @stealthjong : values[] contains strictly increasing values, by increments which are about 0.01 to 1.0 (nothing extremely small, nothing extremely large). Here values[107 to 110] are around 74 and values[1] is rather small, around 0.1

Comment: The "unsafe-math" optimisation is called "unsafe" for a reason. It may give you FASTER code, but it may give you "bad" results too. That is the nature of this functionality. Unfortunately, although plenty long enough, your question doesn't have enough detail to actually answer what the compiler does...

Comment: @Mats : which details do you need? unsafe is OK if one can understand exactly what the unsafeness exactly is, which is the question. Especially the second : can an inlined function containing floating point math be optimized differently (causing different results) at various inlined points in the code?

Comment: A complete piece of code that compiles and produces some reasonable output, including the values required for it to go wrong - that way, I (and others who may know even more on the subject) can compile and look at the generated code with gcc and other compilers/tools. And why don't you try compiling the code with inlining - it is hard to predict exactly what will happen here, and you probably can't rely on it being different in the future - inlining happens fairly early during code-gen phase, so other optimisations will happen on the inlined code.

Comment: Which architecture is this? x86? If so, what kind of floating point code are you using, sse or fpu? The fpu results are unreliable when they spill from register to memory (think context switching for example). Could you try with -mfpmath=sse2 (not sure about the option name)?

Comment: @Sylvain : unreliable maybe, but they should be reproducible. The problem here is not exactness, it's that the same (apparent) calculation leads to two different values. The fpu is not supposed to be a RNG :) I'm already using -mfpmath=sse3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking at disassembly, it seems that funsafe-optimization does change

```
float i1 = ((values[y]+values[y+1])-values[1])*0.5f;
float i2 = ((values[y+1]+values[y+2])-values[1])*0.5f;
```

into:

```
float i1 = ((values[y+1]-values[1])+values[y])*0.5f;
float i2 = ((values[y+1]-values[1])+values[y+2])*0.5f;
```

As it may then compute `(values[y+1]-values[1])` only once.

Then, i2 for y==127 and i1 for y==128 are now computed slightly differently and fpu rounding make the result different.

Writing the calculation as a separate function of y solves the issue. But the question about the problem potentially reappearing if the compiler decides to inline and optimize is still open.

Answer (score 2):

Even `x=y; if (x==y) ...` is not guaranteed to work with these optimizations. It may, for example, wind up comparing a value in a register to a value in memory, and the value in memory may have less precision.

This is possibly what's causing the issue here. In one case, a value could be used from a floating point register and in the other case, there aren't enough registers and a value must be written to memory and then read back. Perhaps `i1` stays in the very last available register, but `i2` has to go in memory.

Or it could be something else entirely. But it's not unexpected.

Comment: No, it seems to come from the fact that unsafe math optimizations does not respect the order of operations. For instance, in a three or more term sum, he may group partial sums as he likes. Here it seems to group : (values[y+1]-values[1]) and discard ordering and parenthese, as he may then compute it once for both calculation lines.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that you that you compare digits that are beyond machine precision for floating point numbers (which is 1e-7 for float and 1e-16 for double). That means you output more digits than you should. If you were to output the variable in binary representation instead of the numerical values I'd guess they are the same. If you're worried that 1e-7 is not enough, I suggest using doubles.

Comment: No, the two slightly different numbers here which cause the problem, are floating-point and they differ by the last float mantissa bit. I do not care of having a more accurate result, but only that the same math formula applied on the same input values produces the same number, bit by bit. This is what unsafe-optimizations is about as it makes optimizations which break that.